# CoreData and the NSComboBox

Tags: xcode, core-data, nscombobox

I have a Mac application that uses CoreData. I have 1 entity "Employee" with 2 attributes, `employeeName` and `employeePin`. I have a drawer window that is used to add employees as well. I want an `NSComboBox` to be populated with the `employeeName` attribute from CoreData but I can't figure it out. Ive got CoreData working like it should but I can't figure out how to bind the `NSComboBox` with that particular attribute.

I created an Array Controller and set the parameter "Managed Object Context" to the App Delegate with the model key path `managedObjectContext` but Im not getting the names to pull up in the combo box. How do i get the names to pull up in the combo box. Any and all help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fully set up the array controller you also need to set the mode to `'Entity Name'` in the identity inspector of the array controller and specify this as `'Employee'`

After that you need to bind the 'content value' of the combo box(in bindings inspector) to `employeeName` of the array controller. (`arrangedObjects`).

i.e in the Bindings inspector,

- click on bind :Array controller
- Controller Key :`arrangedObjects`
- Model Key Path : `employeeName`

Comment: I performed the steps above and the `employeeName` still isn't showing up in the combo box. I have checked the SQLite database and the data is there.